# Entering lines into password promt

Tags: bash, while-loop, command-line, git-bash, unzip

For a uni-assignment I need to write a while-loop for **BASH**-shell (on windows) that tries different passwords line by line from a given *.txt-file* and enter them to unzip a given .*zip-Archive*.

I know how to unzip archives and I know how to echo the *.txt-file* contents line by line, but can't figure out how to combine them:

#1

```
while read pw
    do echo "$pw"
done < passwords.txt
```

#2

```
unzip -P $pw archive.zip
```

Comment: So what is hard? Put `unzip` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to the following way:

```
while read -r pw
do
    if unzip -P "$pw" archive.zip
    then
        break
    fi
done < passwords.txt
```

You can read about `read -r` option [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192790).

Comment: +redirct passwords.txt as input to the while loop `done < passwords.txt`

Comment: Please fix your script by adding the `-r` flag to `read`: `read -r pw`, and by adding double quotes when expanding a variable value in `unzip -P "$pw" archive.zip` and by testing the return value of the command directly rather than addressing the `$?` variable: `if unzip -P "$pw" archive.zip; then`…

Comment: See also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have edited the answer as per suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In bash there are several ways to accomplish this task, like the follow:

```sh
echo -n Please enter the password: 
read -s PASSWORD
echo "Debug: your entered the passowrd \"${PASSWORD}\"."
```

Then call the unzip command...

Comment: seems to me like OP wants an automatic looping method. Your solution involves interaction and there is simply no loop, or unzip. kindly consider providing a more suitable answer that isn't [the same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67618292/13982210)

Comment: other side note, UPPERCASE user-defined variables in shell are not recommended to avoid overwriting or conflicting with environment variables